# nodejs mysql module error while inserting row

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, parse-error

I am having some issue while trying to insert a row into my database.

Here is the structure of my table :

```
mysql> describe emprunt;
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| idEmprunt        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Joueur_idEmprunt | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| valeur_empruntee | float   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| duree_emprunt    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| jour_emprunt     | int(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| mois_emprunt     | int(3)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What my program must do is : 
The client open an HTML page in which there is a button. When clicked, data is sent to the server to add a row in my table.

I give you the whole code so that you may understand, but you should focus on the last lines, the function setEmprunt(..), because it is where the error comes from.

```
var server = require('http').createServer(function(req, res){
        res.end('chargement effectué');
    });
server.listen(8080);    

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var mysql = require('mysql');
//using a pool to manage multi users queries
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'NoNeedToKnowThat', 
    password : 'Neither', 
    database : 'test' //
});

//A client open the HTML page
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Client !!');



    //===================================================
    // Client clicks the button and sends 2, 7000, 15
    //===================================================
    socket.on('setEmprunt', function (aIdJoueur, aSomme, aDuree) {

        pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {

            setEmprunt(connection, aIdJoueur, aSomme, aDuree, function(err){
                if(err) {
                    console.log("error in setEmprunt : "+ err);
                    throw err;
                }
                else
                    console.log("callback of setEmprunt");
            });
            // And done with the connection.
            connection.release();

        });

    }); 


function setEmprunt(aConnection, aIdJoueur, aSomme, aDuree, aCallback){
    var maintenant= new Date(),
        jourEmprunt = maintenant.getDate(),
        moisEmprunt = maintenant.getMonth();
    rowToBeInserted = { Joueur_idEmprunt : aIdJoueur, valeur_empruntee : aSomme, duree_emprunt : aDuree, jour_emprunt : jourEmprunt, mois_emprunt : moisEmprunt };
    console.log("set emprunt de : " + rowToBeInserted);


//There is the problem line
    aConnection.query('INSERT INTO emprunt VALUES ?', rowToBeInserted, aCallback);


}
```

And there is my result :

```
C:\Users\QuentinB\Developpement>node serveur.js
   info  - socket.io started
   info  - handshake authorized ZIH1OSAUuRGHz8G9hCfc
Client !!
set emprunt de : [object Object]
error in setEmprunt : Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syn
tax to use near '`Joueur_idEmprunt` = 2, `valeur_empruntee` = 7000, `duree_emprunt` = 15, `jour_e' at line 1

Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`Joueur_
idEmprunt` = 2, `valeur_empruntee` = 7000, `duree_emprunt` = 15, `jour_e' at line 1
    at Query.Sequence._packetToError (C:\Users\QuentinB\Developpement\giserv5\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:30:14)
```

I know this is the last line of my code which is blocking, because I tried to replace it by :

```
aConnection.query('INSERT INTO emprunt(Joueur_idEmprunt, valeur_empruntee, duree_emprunt, jour_emprunt, mois_emprunt) VALUES('+aIdJoueur+','+aSomme+','+aDuree+','+jourEmprunt+','+moisEmprunt+');', aCallback);
```

and it worked.
I would like to understand why aConnection.query('INSERT INTO emprunt VALUES ?', rowToBeInserted, aCallback) is not working.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick look, I believe you want to use `INSERT INTO...SET ?` not `INSERT INTO...VALUES ?` in your code in this case. The `?` expands into `name=val` pairs, while the VALUES clause is looking for just values.

Comment: You are welcome. Everyone needs a second set of eyes sometimes.